# Prime powers of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there anything special of the special case of prime powers $q^p$ for $q$ prime, if $p$ is also prime? Aside from the fact that we can apply Fermat's little theorem to obtain
$$q^p \equiv q\,\mathrm{mod}\,p$$
and they are an even "smaller" set in the sense of analytic number theory of small sets then the prime powers. Are there any other known properties?

EDIT: The question arose from the order of finite prime groups which have size $q^p$.

Comment: Everything is special, depending on what makes something special to the observer.

Comment: I would rather go for the more objective special in that sense that they exhibit a property which does not apply to the general case if $p$ is an arbitrary positive integer. I am looking for such a property

Comment: There is a unique integral $n^\textrm{th}$ root of this number ($n>1$). However this is also true for $a^p$ where $a$ is not a perfect power and $p$ is prime.